# When is the formfield() method called in Django?

Tags: python, django, widget, custom-field-type

This is a question on making custom fields in Django. I'm making a field called `EditAreaField`, which inherits from `TextField`. Here's what my code looks like:

```
class EditAreaField(models.TextField):
    description = "A field for editing the HTML of a page"
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {}
        defaults['widget'] = EditArea() # setting a new widget
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(EditAreaField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

**On the 5th line**, I'm assigning a custom widget to this field. **On line 6**, I update the parameters.

The problem is, Django sends a parameter `widget` that's set to `django.contrib.admin.widgets.AdminTextareaWidget`, which overrides my EditArea() widget.

How can I change the value that Django is setting? Obviously I could just override their setting by switching lines 5 and 6, so my code looks like:

```
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        defaults['widget'] = EditArea() # override django here
```

But is that really the best way to do it?

As a side note, I couldn't find documentation on the formfield() function anywhere on Django's site: is it deprecated?

Comment: I'm reading up on your question. Here's the link to the docs on formfield [http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.formfield](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.formfield)

Comment: Oops. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.formfield

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `formfield` method is called by the `ModelForm` helper. According to the docs, the `formfield` method should include only a `form_class` attribute to point to the formfield class for this custom model field. This is a custom (or default) form field class, which is where the default widget is defined

```
from myapp.forms import MyCustomFormField

#create a custom model field
class EditAreaField(models.TextField):
  def formfield(self, **kwargs):
    defaults={'form_class': MyCustomFormField}#pass our custom field as form_class
    defaults.update(kwargs)
    return super(EditAreaField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

Comment: shouldn't it return the super... ?